# Why does "del x" not change the result of a generator while x.append does?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, generator

I can do this:

```
>>> x = [2,3,4] 
>>> y = (v * 2 for v in x)
>>> del x                          # x is deleted
>>> print(list(y))                 # y still exists
[4, 6, 8]
```

This may let me think generator y is independent from list x. But I can also do this:

```
>>> a = [2, 3, 4]
>>> b = (v * 2 for v in a)
>>> a.append(5)                   # change a
>>> print(list(b))                # b is also changed
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

This makes me feel that generator b is still pointing to list a. So I am wondering how generator is actually constructed. Or maybe there is something about how x is deleted in the first case.

Comment: `del x` doesn't necessarily delete the object being referenced by `x`. It simply deletes the *name `x`*. So, yes, the generator still has a reference to `a`.

Comment: So the content is still in memory? Then when is memory actually released?

Comment: The memory is release when all references to the object have been deleted. In your case, the generator still holds a reference to the object after the name `x` has been deleted

Comment: It depends on your Python implementation. CPython uses reference counting (actually, it also uses a gc to detect and free reference cycles). When there are no more references to your object, the memory is deallocated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`del` doesn't delete objects.  It deletes *names*.  Objects will still exist as long as there is any reference to them.  The name `x` and your generator `y` both reference a single object (the list).  If you do `del x` you remove the name `x`, but the generator still holds its reference.  If you modify `x`, the generator sees it, because it is referring to the same object.

Answer (score 4):

Generator expressions work on the concept of [*lazy evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Instead of storing the entire list `[4, 6, 8]`, in memory, the generator stores a definition for `(x * 2 for x in <some list>)` and computes the next value only when needed.

One of the things stored in the definition is the reference to all source variables to be used in computing the expression. When `x` is used in the generator expression, its reference is stored and later dereferenced on a per-need basis.

Now, doing

```
del x
```

Will only decrement the *reference counter* associated with this value. In both cases, there are two references (`x` as well as the reference in the generator) until you delete one of them. The generator reference still exists, which is why it can be evaluated.

Comment: It is misleading to say that "all source variables used" are stored.  In fact, only the target expression (`x*2` in this case) is lazily evaluated --- and because it is lazily evaluated, it *will* reflect changes to variables used there.  It is only the iteration source (`x` here) that is eagerly evaluated.  For instance, if you do something like `g = (a*b for a in x)`, the values from the generator will reflect the value of `b` at the time the generator is iterated, not the value of `b` at the time the generato was created.

Comment: @BrenBarn perhaps it is more correct to say that source *references* are stored? Whereas the iteration source is eagerly evaluated?

Comment: @BrenBarn I think you misunderstood the meaning behind that sentence, but I've edited it for better clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting `x` has no effect as long as the generator keeps a reference to `x`. This is just like:

```
x = [2,3,4] 
y=x
del x
print(y)
```

except the reference isn't kept in a named variable, but internally by the generator.